# .get() not able to get results of checkboxes

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tkinter

See the following snippet of code:

```
def choose_ID():
    import ttk
    global single_ID
    id = BooleanVar()
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    label1 = Label(toplevel, text = "Choose a User ID.", width = 40).pack(anchor=W, pady=5)
    for items in range(len(single_ID)):
        id = Checkbutton(toplevel, text=single_ID[items], variable=single_ID[items])
        id.pack(anchor=W, padx=5)
    single_run_but = Button(toplevel, text = "Run", width=10, height=1, command=run_command).pack(anchor=S, pady=5)
    id.get()
```

Its purpose is to open a popup window with a number of checkboxes (the number could be anything from 1 to 100) containing user id's that have been passed to the function from earlier in the script.

The problem is with the id.get() line at the end. When it runs it errors, saying "Checkbutton instance has no attribute 'get'"

What do I need to change to be able to note which of the checkboxes have been checked (it could be only one or multiple boxes)?

Many thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time you set `id` is in the for loop. During this, you set `id` to be a checkbutton, which does not have the `get()` method.

What you want to do is use the `get()` method on an `IntVar` that is associated with the checkbutton through the `variable` attribute. You can keep references to these variables in a list. I've made a small example of how to dynamically create checkbuttons and still be able to get their values.

```
from Tkinter import *

def run_command():
    selected_ids = []
    for i, id_var in enumerate(id_var_list):
        if id_var.get():
            selected_ids.append(id_list[i])
    print selected_ids

root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "Choose a User ID.", width = 40).pack(anchor=W, pady=5)

id_list = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID100']
id_checkbutton_list = []
id_var_list = []

for item in id_list:
    id_var = IntVar()
    id_checkbutton = Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=id_var)
    id_checkbutton.pack(anchor=W, padx=5)

    id_var_list.append(id_var)
    id_checkbutton_list.append(id_checkbutton)

Button(root, text = "Run", width=10, height=1, command=run_command).pack(anchor=S, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @fhdrsdg, that's all good stuff! How would you translate the 0 or 1 that id_var.get() gives you back into a user id so it can be actioned elsewhere?

Comment: I've edited the `run_command()` to get the selected user ids.